# Online Code Editor

Tags: ide, text-editor

The major online IDEs are hosted on the service provider's server. Examples are Kodingen, Cloud9, ShiftEdit. Hence they would be unavailable if the external server was down for some reason, and I prefer to do my computing on my own computer anyway.

Does anyone know of an online IDE or editor (preferably just an editor - a simple implementation of the Ace or CodeMirror JS editors) which can be downloaded and run on localhost (on a local LAMP server)? I've found two so far - Eclipse Orion and Wiode, but I don't like either of them very much, and I'm looking for alternatives.

Also suitable are browser extensions which run natively on the browser (offline) without going to some external site. An example would be SourceKit for Chrom(e/ium).

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid, but why would one want an online tool if it's for running it locally ?

Comment: So what's wrong with Ace then?

Comment: @back2dos: Nothing wrong with Ace, but can it be run on my local server at all?

Comment: @iDevlop: Good point. It's just that I'm trying to set up a Chromebook-style workflow in which I do everything in the browser. Some people would even say that that's how the future is going to be.

Comment: @Atriya: I figured out that, but can you install a LAMP server on a Chromebook ? And then you're stuck on THAT machine, which makes you lose the advantages of beeing "in the cloud"...

Comment: Hi Atriya, questions about development tools are [off-topic here](http://programmmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: What you are looking for is Brackets - http://brackets.io/ . And like the cloud editors it is powered by Javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you can take a look to this article:
[Wikipedia ― Comparison of JavaScript-based source code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors).

For more, here is some tools that seem to fit with your request:
***All of these software are downloadable, and usable on a local server.***

- [EditArea](http://sourceforge.net/projects/editarea/) ― **[Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/editarea/files/latest/download)** ― [*Demo as FileEditor*](http://fileeditor.binary-technology.ro/index.php?r=site/page&view=test) who is a [Yii Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/fileeditor/) ― (*Apache Software License, BSD, LGPL*)

  > Here is EditArea, a free javascript editor for source code. It allow to write well formated source code with line numerotation, tab support, search & replace (with regexp) and live syntax highlighting (customizable).
- [CodePress](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress/) ― **[Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress/files/latest/download)** ― [*Demo of Joomla! CodePress Plugin*](http://demo10.joomler.net/content/view/14/2/) ― (*LGPL*) ― It doesn't work in Chrome and it looks like development has ceased.

  > CodePress is web-based source code editor with syntax highlighting written in JavaScript that colors text in real time while it's being typed in the browser.
- [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) ― **[Download](http://codemirror.net/codemirror.zip)** ― [*One of the many demo*](http://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html) ― (*[MIT-style](http://codemirror.net/LICENSE) license + optional [commercial support](http://codemirror.net/#commercial)*)

  > CodeMirror is a JavaScript library that can be used to create a relatively pleasant editor interface for code-like content ― computer programs, HTML markup, and similar. If a mode has been written for the language you are editing, the code will be coloured, and the editor will optionally help you with indentation
- [Ace Ajax.org Cloud9 Editor](http://ace.ajax.org/) ― [*Demo*](http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html) ― (*Mozilla tri-license (MPL/GPL/LGPL)*)

  > Ace is a standalone code editor written in JavaScript. Our goal is to create a web based code editor that matches and extends the features, usability and performance of existing native editors such as TextMate, Vim or Eclipse. It can be easily embedded in any web page and JavaScript application. Ace is developed as the primary editor for [Cloud9 IDE](http://www.cloud9ide.com/) and the successor of the Mozilla Skywriter (Bespin) Project.
  >   **Getting the code**
  >   Ace is a community project. We actively encourage and support contributions. The Ace source code is hosted on GitHub. It is released under the Mozilla tri-license (MPL/GPL/LGPL). This is the same license used by Firefox. This license is friendly to all kinds of projects, whether open source or not. Take charge of your editor and add your favorite language highlighting and keybindings!
  >   `git clone git://github.com/ajaxorg/ace.git`

Moreover, it seems that this question have been asked twice on [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/), so you can probably gather more information here:

- [Textarea that can do syntax highlighting on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1619167/492638)
- *textarea with syntax / code highlighting* **dead link, question removed *(`q/1505761`)***

[AjaXplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info/) implements CodeMirror's advanced editor. This provides you with file management and syntax highlighted code editing in a single, multi-user application.

Comment: Thanks. I already know about that article. The point is - can CodeMirror or Ace be downloaded to run on my local server? That's what I want. I know that something like Kodingen can use both Ace and CodeMirror as the editor component. But I don't want that, since it'll run on Kodingen's server and not mine.

Comment: All the software I put in my link are downloadable and free (I put the *licences* at the right of the *Demo*. If you click on the link, just locate the download page ^^

Comment: I add some download links for help you, but you need to use Git to get Ace.

Comment: @Pascal Qyy: Thanks, I didn't know that these could be downloaded and used locally. I downloaded codemirror.zip from the link you provided, and unzipped it. Inside are lots of html and js files. But how do I actually use it? I need an interface where I can open, edit and save files - as a bare minimum.

Comment: My first link, EditArea, come with a link to live demo of [FileEditor](http://fileeditor.binary-technology.ro/index.php) who is exactly what you are asking... [Here is the How To about it](http://fileeditor.binary-technology.ro/index.php?r=site/page&view=howto)